# R shiny modularizing

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, modularity

I'm not seeing the text from the `dynamicUIModule` in the output. What's wrong with my modularized Shiny app?

```
    library(shiny)

dynamicUIModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynamic_ui <- renderUI({
    h3("This is a test!")
  })
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num_input", "Enter a number:", value = 1),
  uiOutput("dynamic_ui"),  # This will display content from serverOnlyModule
  textOutput("display_num")
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Calling the server-only module
  callModule(dynamicUIModule, "dynamic1")
  
  # Other server logic
  output$display_num <- renderText({
    paste0("Squared value: ", input$num_input^2)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You have no module server, so the module UI has no dependencies, so Shiny “optimises it out”. You also seem to be confusing the modules Uni and server functions and not providing it with an I’d.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I should have added the UI module as well. For example:

```
library(shiny)


sidebarUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("dynamic_ui"))
  )
}

dynamicUIModule <- function(input, output, session, squaredValue) {
  output$dynamic_ui <- renderUI({
    if (squaredValue() > 10) {
      sliderInput(session$ns("dynamic_slider"), "Value is large! Adjust:", min = 1, max = 100, value = 50)
    } else {
      h3("Value is small!")
    }
  })
}


library(shiny)

# Source the module

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num_input", "Enter a number:", value = 1),
  sidebarUI("dynamic1"),  # This ID should match the ID in renderUI of the module
  textOutput("display_num")
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  squaredValue <- reactive({
    input$num_input^2
  })
  
  # Calling the dynamic UI module
  callModule(dynamicUIModule, "dynamic1", squaredValue = squaredValue)
  
  # Using the squared value in the main server logic
  output$display_num <- renderText({
    
    paste0("Squared value: ", squaredValue())
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```